# Is it possible to detect whether a class is being called directly by the class or indirectly by a base class?

Tags: python, class, inheritance, detection

I am making a program with some inherited classes but my program needs to know whether a class' functions are being called directly from the class or from a base class e.g.

```py
class Letters():
    def letter(): ...
    ...

class ABC(Letters):
    def __init__(self):
        if from_base_class:
            raise Exception
    def A(): ...
    def B(): ...
    def C(): ...

==== terminal: ====

>>> myclass = ABC()
>>> myclass.letter()
[with all of the line numbers here]
Exception
```

How can I implement this into my code?

Comment: Please update your question with more examples of when and when not exceptions should be thrown.

Comment: Your letters class does not have an ABC() method and ABC doesn't have a base class.  Please provide an example that we can actually run and describe your expected result.

Comment: oh no im so stupid I forgot to make ABC inherit from Letters :P i have fixed my code

Comment: So what is `myclass.ABC()`?

Comment: oh its a typo i change it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So did you mean to raise an exception?

```py
class Letters():
    def letter(self): ...
    ...

class ABC(Letters):
    def letter(self):
        raise NotImplementedError
```